Convert audio file, but keep original
I'm using the command
ffmpeg -i FILE.mp4 -vn -acodec copy FILE.m4a

to convert the MP4 video into an audio file.  This works fine, but afterwards, I have only FILE.m4a left and the input, FILE.mp4, disappeared.
Is there an option for ffmpeg which makes the input unchanged? Of course I can write a shell wrapper, which makes a copy of the input file, calls ffmpeg, and then restores the original, but I wonder whether this can be done simpler.
UPDATE problem can't be reproduced. Command seems to work fine.

I tested the command that you mention, and I can see no changes being made to the input file.  If the input file was removed, then it was not the command that you show that removed it.

@Kusalananda : I don't know what blunder I did back then, but I can't reproduce it annymore. Thanks for verifying my command.
